# Confused about how to exactly determine the complexity of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines

Let's take this algorithm as an example.

$PATH$ = {$G$, s, t | $G$ is a directed graph that has a directed path from s to t }.

Prove that $PATH \in P $.

Ok, I know the basic algorithm is to start from node s, place a mark on it, and then look over the rest of the edges and place a mark from node s to node x if there exists a edge from node s to node x. If you place a mark on node t, then accept; otherwise, keep doing this until you run out of nodes, which implies you reject.

I'm getting caught up in implementation details, really. I can most likely envision a turning machine that can do this in polynomial time, but I don't know if this is the right way to go about it,per say. In Sipser, it seems like a very "hand wavy proof." When I encounter an algorithm should I first figure out a way to implement it on a reasonable Turing machine? Or is there a better way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: What is your confusion, now? Designing, implementing, or analysing the algorithm?

Comment: I think you may profit from reading some of [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844).

Comment: Hand-wavy proofs are the standard. You have to read a few of them to know what amount of hand-waving is normal. Unfortunately, being any more detailed is more difficult than its worth – for both writer and reader.

Comment: Basically, people will write proofs up the point where the can say "if you paid me a million dollars to do this totally boring and unproductive work, then I could write a complete proof without any gaps".

Comment: For the record, I heartily disagree with Yuval: the average level of rigor in algorithm analyses is too low and the results obtained are usually not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that an algorithm is in $P$ you basically have two options:

1. Show how to solve it using a number of operations that is polynomial in the size of the input. This means you have to specify a Turing machine to do it, and prove that each of the operations takes a polynomial amount of time. Alternatively, you would prove that the turing machine spends a polynomial amount of steps in any non-accept/reject state.
2. Show that your problem can be reformulated as a already-known problem previously proven to be in $P$. Here you have to prove that the reformulation is correct and that it takes polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it should be simple.

You calculate the set of all nodes that can be reached from s. You start with { s }. How many operations does it take at most to add another node to the set or to find that no more nodes can be added? How often will you add another node to the set? With that information, the problem is easily solved.